# How do I keep track of a value on other environment in R

Tags: r, function, closures, lexical-scope

I'm trying to make an assignment for an online course and I'm stuck at trying to keep a value on cache. Basically,there would be two functions: One would be a closure function and host a variable to keep track of values on cache. The other one would be responsible for managing the matrices. Problem is the programn doesn't seem to keep the value of m stored for each matrix and always considers that there are already values on the cache. How can I keep track of the cached values?

```
makeCacheMatrix <- function(x = matrix()) {
    m<-NULL
    set<-function(y){
        x<<-y
        m<<-NULL
    }
    get<-function()x
    inverse<-function(x) m<<-solve(x)
    cache<-function() m
    list(set=set(x),get=get(),inverse=inverse(x),cache=cache())
}


## Write a short comment describing this function
cacheSolve <- function(x, ...) {
        ## Return a matrix that is the inverse of 'x'
        n<-makeCacheMatrix(x)$cache
        if (!is.null(n)){
            print("Loading from cache")
            return(n)
        }
        else{
            makeCacheMatrix(x)$set
            data<-makeCacheMatrix(x)$get
            makeCacheMatrix(data)$inverse

            makeCacheMatrix(data)$cache
    }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you are attempting here. My guess is that you want to have a cache so that if you need to run a resource-intensive function on an object then you only have to run it once, but thereafter be able to access the stored result of the computation. Whether the computation has been run or not, you want the same interface to access the result.

You could do that this way:

```r
store_matrix_for_cache <- function(x = matrix()) {
  m <<- NULL
  function()
  {
    x <<- x
    list(get = x, cache = m, solve = function() m <<- solve(x))
  }
}

get_cached_result <- function(cache, ...) 
{
  if (is.null(cache()$cache))
  {
    cat("Solving before returning from cache\n")
    cache()$solve()
  } 
  else 
  {
    cat("Loading from cache\n")
  }

  return(cache()$cache)
}
```

So let's test it on some sample data:

```r
set.seed(69)
my_mat   <- matrix(sample(9), nrow = 3)

my_mat
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    2    5    9
#> [2,]    4    1    6
#> [3,]    7    3    8
```

We start by writing our matrix to the cache. Note our "expensive" `solve` function hasn't been called yet, so this is computationally cheap:

```
my_cache <- store_matrix_for_cache(my_mat)
```

When we come to extract the result, then on the first occasion, we will trigger the `solve` calculation:

```r
get_cached_result(my_cache)
#> Solving before returning from cache
#>           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
#> [1,]  2.000000  1.0000000 -2.0000000
#> [2,] -1.727273 -0.4545455  1.5454545
#> [3,]  1.090909  0.1818182 -0.8181818
```

However, the second (and subsequent times) we access the cache, we don't trigger the `solve` function, but instead return the stored result.

```r
get_cached_result(my_cache)
#> Loading from cache
#>           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
#> [1,]  2.000000  1.0000000 -2.0000000
#> [2,] -1.727273 -0.4545455  1.5454545
#> [3,]  1.090909  0.1818182 -0.8181818
```

Note also that our accessor function can be shortened by removing the `cat` messages now we're happy it works as expected:

```r
get_cached_result <- function(cache, ...) 
{
  if (is.null(cache()$cache)) cache()$solve()
  cache()$cache
}
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much. I used your example to fix my code and thanks to you it's working now.